# gdb/ddd can't find raise.c when debugging assert(), it is looking in my home directory

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, libc

I use gdb (ddd) to debug my C/C++ projects.

Whenever an assert fails, I can debug the program as normal and backtrace to the assert which failed, but first I get an annoying popup

[image]

I assume `raise.c` defines `assert`, but ddd is looking within my home directory instead of `/usr/...` or something like that.

I may or may not have the debugging packages installed (I'm on Ubuntu), but the main question is: why is gdb looking within `$HOME` for this source?

Comment: The assert macro expands to call a function that reports the error.  That function is defined, it seems, in `raise.c` — and for some reason, the debugger thinks it was compiled under what is presumably your home directory.  More than that, I can't say — I've not seen the problem, but that's not surprising since I don't use `ddd`.

Comment: Can you run just gdb (not ddd) and see if the error message is the same? Gdb typically complains about `../sysdeps/unix/sysv/...`. It could be that ddd is trying to be helpful by canonicalizing the pathname. 99% of the time, that would indeed be helpful, but not here.

Comment: Yes, gdb is using a relative path to ../`sysdeps`

Answer (score 3):

Since the glibc debuginfo package `libc6-dbg` is installed on your system, gdb will look in `/usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so` to map instruction addresses into source file names and line numbers.

The section of that file that contains the info for `__GI_raise` has the following attributes that indicate where the source code might be found (on Ubuntu 16.04):

```
<0><688bd>: Abbrev Number: 1 (DW_TAG_compile_unit)
    <688c3>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x9137): ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c
    <688c7>   DW_AT_comp_dir    : (indirect string, offset: 0x9010): /build/glibc-Cl5G7W/glibc-2.23/signal
```

Ubuntu doesn't ship source code in the base distribution, so your system doesn't have any glibc source in `/build/glibc-Cl5G7W/glibc-2.23`, so gdb looks (unsuccessfully) for `raise.c` in a few other directories according to its rules [Specifying Source Directories](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html) and eventually gives up, with the error message

```
54  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

Then, ddd calls `SourceView::full_path("../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c")` to canonicalize the pathname, taking your working directory into account, and displays the error dialog box in your question.

See [GDB complaining about missing raise.c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278881/gdb-complaining-about-missing-raise-c/48287761#48287761) for how to install glibc source on Ubuntu.