# GDB - read.c: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gdb

I am trying to attach GDB to a running process and but am getting the below error.

```
/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c: No such file or directory.
```

Code compiled with `gcc` as so, `gcc -ggdb -o OutputFile InputFile`.

The command I am running is `gdb Program pid`.
So far as I can tell from other posts this is the correct command.

I get a confirmation of sorts from GDB with this line, `Attaching to program: /path/to/file`.

Do I need to specify the path to the underlying `C` files somehow?

Running this on `Debian 4.17.8-1kali1`

Comment: You can find it [here](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c).

Comment: This answers in the dup seemed a little light, so I have added a new one.

Comment: Related: [GDB complaining about missing raise.c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278881/gdb-complaining-about-missing-raise-c/48287761#48287761)