# Debugging Debian-packaged libraries

Tags: debugging, gdb, debian

I have a C program `foo` which I am compiling and debugging with GDB just fine. (I'm using QtCreator as an IDE if relevant).

When I call function `bar()`, in library `libbar.so.1`, in debian package `libbar1`, I don't get the expected result so I'd like to step into it.

- `apt source libbar1` gets sources for `libbar.so.1` and I've found the implementation of `bar()` in `/tmp/libbar-1.0/src/bar.c`.
- `apt install libbar1-dbgsym` installs the debugging symbols to `/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/{22,fb}/*.debug`

How can I debug `foo` and step into the implementation of `bar()` in GDB?

---

I suspect I must have to add startup commands to GDB with the location of debug symbols and sources.

I've tried adding this to gdb startup commands:

```
> directory /tmp/libbar-1.0/src/
```

Next, I'm thinking it might be related to `set substitute-path from to`, but I'm not sure whether `/tmp/libbar-1.0/src` goes in `from` or `to` and what the other one would be.

Comment: My answer in [GDB complaining about missing raise.c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278881/gdb-complaining-about-missing-raise-c), which shows how to tell GDB where it should look for the glibc sources, may help here. So (1) place a breakpoint at `bar` and run until it stops there (2) type `info source` to see the compilation-dir (3) type `set substitute-path compilation-dir dir-with-sources`

Comment: Please don't use `libbar` -- show the _actual_ library you are having trouble with.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The IDE I'm using doesn't make it easy for me to "type `info source`".  But your other answer really helped.  Now that I've gone through the whole process and re-read your comment, you were spot on.  It just took me some time to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

[GDB complaining about missing raise.c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278881/gdb-complaining-about-missing-raise-c) gave me a start to solving this.   This is the full solution where I don't have the luxury of halting on a signal during runtime:

We need the following from the Debian archive:

1. `sudo apt install libbar1`:  This deploys `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbar.so.1`.  It's already installed if your program is running.
2. `sudo apt install libbar1-dbgsym`: This deploys `/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/22/*.debug`
3. `apt source libbar1`:  This deploys `./libbar-1.0/src/bar.c`

Now we need to open the library in gdb and look for the original source path:

```
$ gdb /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbar.so.1
...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbar.so.1...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/22/8b32043be712018feacacb319a48ebf5400ebf.debug...done
(gdb) info sources 
./obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/./src/bar.c
```

The `./obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/.` is important.  This was the original location where the sources were built.  We need to substitute that with the location of our sources so GDB can find them and add that new path to our list of searchable sources:

```
(gdb) set substitute-path ./obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/. /tmp/libbar-1.0
(gdb) directory /tmp/libbar-1.0
Source directories searched: /tmp/libbar-1.0:$cdir:$cwd
(gdb) info sources 
/tmp/libbar-1.0/src/bar.c
(gdb) list bar
2       int bar(int x) {
3         return x+1;
4       }
```

You're using QtCreator to drive `gdb`.  In that case under "Tools > Options > Debugger > GDB" there is a text box labeled: "Additional Startup Commands".  Add the following to that text box and you can debug!

```
set substitute-path ./obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/. /tmp/libbar-1.0
directory /tmp/libbar-1.0
```

Comment: Setting `dir /tmp/libbar-1.0` should be sufficient (`substitute-path` should not be required).